# Gnome not starting on 19.10 with my existing user but does start with a new user

Tags: gnome, 19.10

I'm getting the pesky

> Oh no! Something has gone wrong.
>
> A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please logout and
>   try again.

But if I create a new user it works.

Where do I start looking? Are there logs I can look at?

Comment: Have you added any extensions or made any recent changes to settings (esp. those that will impact gnome such as extensions). New user accounts usually have extensions turned off (or set to default with Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help.

So there was something in the syslog which helped me out.

In the syslog I saw:

> Bail out!
>   Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkicontheme.c:4277:gtk_icon_info_load_icon_finish:
>   assertion failed: (icon_info_get_pixbuf_ready (icon_info))

And this looks like it matches [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1787512) bug.

The fix for me, which the bug indicates is to remove the file:

> .config/autostart/indicator-multiload.desktop

[indicator-multiload](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/indicator-multiload-is-a-gnome-applet-style-system-monitor-for-your-desktop-panel) is a useful load monitoring tool that shows your systenm load in the gnome panel. I really miss it.

Comment: Please document the issue in your anwer rather than only providing the link

Comment: added as requested