# "oh no something has gone wrong" after clean install of 19.10 LVM and making changes

Tags: login, 19.10, lvm, error-handling

**EDIT**

**Please can someone point me to the logfile/whatever that will provide some information on what causes this message to pop up. I'm sure I can fix it, provided I have more information than some Microsoft-like generic message.**

**I could even follow kernel code, but without some pointers on where to look for what the problem actually is, trawling blindly through millions of line of code isn't gonna work.**

**/Edit**

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.10 onto a drive (SSHD) with boot partition and then LVM partitions for swap, root & home, with another 2 'vms' & 'bulk' leaving 25% of VG free.

To copy stuff into 'bulk' I would mkdir a folder in terminal, use (sudo nautilus) to change owner & group from root to my account, then copy stuff (normal nautilus) from old drives. Also installed new software as I went.

I realised 'bulk' was too small and did lvextend +256G in terminal. Strange: I still couldn't copy my files as not enough room. Did a reboot fine, except when I tried to log in, (I think) I got [image] 
How can I work out WHY it's failed, so I can fix it? (logging out and in again does NOT fix it)

Comment: Realised maybe I should do a `resize2fs <drive>` which worked (after booting with another computer), but still can't log in.

Comment: Start with /var/log/syslog. Also look in /var/crash. And /var/log/apport. Did you login to X? Or Wayland?

Comment: I've located the text in gnome-session and created this issue about the screen being useless https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-session/-/issues/62 If you have suggestions on how to improve this screen please add suggestions there and vote up if you agree.

Answer (score 1):

I trawled through `/var/log/syslog` (thanks, user535733). It had over 4K lines when limited by manual timed bookends, and 'error' occurred 65 times. I noticed the specific error when comparing it to a working 19.10. The lines in question are

> Feb 10 14:44:02 HP gnome-shell[2035]: gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple: assertion 'dest_height > 0' failed
>
> Feb 10 14:44:02 HP gnome-shell[2035]: [AppIndicatorSupport-WARN] Attempting to re-register :1.108/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/multiload; resetting instead
>
> Feb 10 14:44:02 HP gnome-shell[2035]: **
>
> Feb 10 14:44:02 HP gnome-shell[2035]: Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkicontheme.c:4277:gtk_icon_info_load_icon_finish: assertion failed: (icon_info_get_pixbuf_ready (icon_info))
>
> Feb 10 14:44:02 HP gnome-shell[2035]: Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkicontheme.c:4277:gtk_icon_info_load_icon_finish: assertion failed: (icon_info_get_pixbuf_ready (icon_info))
>
> Feb 10 14:44:02 HP gnome-shell[2035]: GNOME Shell crashed with signal 6

The fix [Gnome not starting on 19.10 with my existing user but does start with a new user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186962/gnome-not-starting-on-19-10-with-my-existing-user-but-does-start-with-a-new-user/1186967) was to remove `~/.config/autostart/indicator-multiload.desktop`

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Virtualbox or Vimware try to enable  3D acceleration by going to setting > Display > enable 3D acceleration Hope will help

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me on Ubuntu 20.04